# How do I gracefully migrate logged-in users to a new version of my React Native app?

Tags: react-native, architecture, frontend

As my React Native app grows, I inevitably refactor old code and add new features/endpoints. As a result, the data structure between version releases can vary and since I don't want to force users to log out after each update, I end up in a situation where users are missing the data required for the new features/endpoints. How do I gracefully migrate each existing user to a new version to ensure data integrity?

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit / are you referring to the storage / the API design? When you say users are missing the data required for features / endpoints are you referring to something you pull?

Answer (score 0):

One method might be to create a conversion utility that gets trigger on every app start. Let's say you have the following changes.

Version 1:
you have a person object that has the following property:

```
person = {
    fullName: "Mike S Smith"
}
```

version 2, you changed the object to:

```
person = {
    firstname: "Mike",
    middleName: "S",
    lastNight: "Smith"
}
```

you method will look something like this:

```
const conversionMethod = (verison, data) => {
    if (version === 2 && data.person.fullName) {
      //do the conversion
    }
```

Comment: So a manual migration script for each data change in the API/app

Comment: yeah, that's the basic idea.